# Connecting Servo to Arduino (branded) Robot

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to attach a servo on an Arduino (branded) Robot but not sure whhich pin to use for the bellow code.
Most people seem to recommend to use pin 9 and 10 to control the servo for arduino Unos.
However, I  can't use Pin 9 because that is already used as the Slave Select pin for the LCD.
I have tried attaching it to pins TKD0-TKD3 by calling them pins 19-22 in `myservo.attach()`. The code runs but the servo doesn't rotate and only gets hot and/or twitches.

Could the problem be something other than incorrect pin connection?

### Thanks,

I have been referencing these for the Control board pin mapping:
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Robot)
http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/grappling-with-the-arduino-robot-control-board

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
            

int pos = 0;    

void setup() 
{ 

  myservo.attach(19);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
} 



void loop() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos < 60; pos += 1)  
  {                                  
myservo.write(pos);              
delay(15);                        
  } 
  for(pos = 60; pos>=1; pos-=1)    
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              
    delay(15);                       
  } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a regular Arduino Uno that you can try with the servo? This would just be so you could verify there isn't something wrong with the servo. Your code is fine. Do you have the servo wired correctly to the robot? Is your plug reversed? These are just some ideas of things to check.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I don't have an Arduino Uno handy but I used another servo to verify. Yes I believe the wiring is correct and I tried various combinations to make sure

Answer (score 0):

You have this robot, right?

[Arduino Robot](http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/grappling-with-the-arduino-robot-control-board)

And you are using a classic servo (3 pins, yellow red and black cable)? If so.... Watch out. According to the schematic, the pinout of the connector on the board (e.g. TKD0) is

```
+5V
AD1
GND
```

While usually servos have

```
DATA
+5V
GND
```

So.. you have to make a short cable to invert the pins.

If that's not the problem.. Are you sure that 19 is the right number for the pin? I can't find references, but i suggest you to call it TKD0 (which is probably a macro defining the right pin), as arduino designers suggest you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I've used jumper wires to invert the pins so I don't believe it's a problem with the wiring. From reading the documentation (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Robot), I think that the following designations can be used to run a servo:
    19 == A1 == TKD0, 
    20 == A2 == TKD1, 
    21 == A3 == TKD2, 
    22 == A4 == TKD3, I have tried putting 'TKD0' in myservo.attach() but the code does not accept this as a value because it doesn't run.

Comment: Well, yes ;) I can see it now. Well, there are just 3 more suggestions I can think of. 1) Try using A1 instead of 19, even if they should be the same. 2) Try to attach a LED to the pin and to make it blink. So you can see what is the problem. 3) the best test: attach an oscilloscope to the pin and see what passes on that line. Moreover you can check the voltages on the pins.

Comment: Thank you heaps! I tried using A4 instead and using an oscilloscope to isolate the issue and my servo is working now!

Comment: So the problem was just using 19 instead of A1? Or you were using A1 instead of A4?